# How to pull even numbers for an Array in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

Let's say we have the following document:

```
db.test.insert({a: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})
```

How to remove all even numbers and just left `[3, 5, 7]`? Can this be accomplished by using the `$pull` operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull all even elements from your array using the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) update operator and  the [`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/) query operator. To update multiple documents I suggest you use the [`updateMany`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) method and for single update you should use the [`updateOne`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) method because [`update`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) is highlighted as deprecated in official language driver. The problem is that shell method lagged behind the drivers. Also nobody really writes application in the shell.

```js
db.test.updateMany({}, { "$pull": { "a": { "$mod": [ 2, 0 ] } } } )
```